# How to create dynamic HTML table in R

Tags: css, r, dataframe, html-table, kableextra

I am using the following structured dataframe in R.

Dataframe<-

```
seq      count  percentage   Marking     count     Percentage     batch_no   count    Percentage
FRD      1      12.50%       S1          2         25.00%         6          1        12.50%
FHL      1      12.50%       S2          1         12.50%         7          2        25.00%
ABC      2      25.00%       S3          1         12.50%         8          2        25.00%
DEF      1      12.50%       Hold        2         25.00%         9          1        12.50%
XYZ      1      12.50%       NA          1         12.50%         NA         1        12.50%
ZZZ      1      12.50%       (Blank)     1         12.50%         (Blank)    1        12.50%
FRD      1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
NA       1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
(Blank)  0      0.00%          -         -           -             -         -           -
Total    8      112.50%        -         8         100.00%         -         8         100.00%
```

The dataframe have number of columns static but number of rows can be vary from. For Example with some condition number of rows might be 15 or less may be 4 or 5.

I need to add table header color as light green with bold font and last row of the table as yellow with bold font. Also, Need to add the condition that if `Percentage` of Hold in marking and `Percentage` of 8 in batch_no is >25% mark it as a dark red with bold white font.

If possible, can we add the suffix in `S3` as `S3 (In Progress)` and `9` as `9 (In Progress) where the font of (In Progress) will be 2 font less than variable name.

The added text `(In Progress)` should be in yellow font with bold.

I'm Using the below mentioned code:

```
library(tableHTML)
library(dplyr)

add_font <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub('\\(', '\\(<font size="-1">', x)
  x <- gsub('\\)', '</font>\\)', x)
  return(prettyNum(x, big.mark = ','))
}


    Html_Table<-Dataframe %>% 
      mutate(`Marking` = add_font(`Marking`),
             `batch_no` = add_font(`batch_no`)) %>% 
      tableHTML(rownames = FALSE, 
                escape = FALSE,
                widths = rep(100, 12),
                caption = "Dataframe: Test",
                theme='scientific') %>% 
      add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border","font-size"),
                                 c("bold", "1px solid black","16px"))) %>%
      add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")), rows = 0:1)%>%
      add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue"))) %>%
      add_css_row(css = list('background-color', '#f2f2f2'),
                  rows = odd(1:10)) %>%
      add_css_row(css = list('background-color', '#e6f0ff'),
                  rows = even(1:10)) %>%
      add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color","font-weight"), c("yellow", "bold")), 
                   rows = even(2:3)) %>%
      add_css_row(css = list(c("font-style","font-size"), c("italic","12px")), 
                   rows = 4:8)
```

Comment: have a look at `flextable`, which allows to export html table, do conditional coloring, formatting and so on

Comment: @denis: Thanks, I'll try to use `flextable` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use exactly what you did with `add_font` to get what you need with tableHTML

```
library(tableHTML)
library(dplyr)
Dataframe <- read.table(text='seq      count  percentage   Marking     count     percentage     batch_no   count    percentage
FRD      1      12.50%       S1          2         25.00%         6          1        12.50%
FHL      1      12.50%       S2          1         12.50%         7          2        25.00%
ABC      2      25.00%       S3          1         12.50%         8          2        25.00%
DEF      1      12.50%       Hold        2         25.00%         9          1        12.50%
XYZ      1      12.50%       NA          1         12.50%         NA         1        12.50%
ZZZ      1      12.50%       (Blank)     1         12.50%         (Blank)    1        12.50%
FRD      1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
NA       1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
(Blank)  0      0.00%          -         -           -             -         -           -
Total    8      112.50%        -         8         100.00%         -         8         100.00%',
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% as_tibble()
names_orig <- Dataframe %>% names()

# add numeric columns to get the conditions
Dataframe$percentage.1_num <- gsub("%", "", Dataframe$percentage) %>% as.numeric()
Dataframe$percentage.2_num <- gsub("%", "", Dataframe$percentage.1) %>% as.numeric()

add_font <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub('\\(', '\\(<font size="-1">', x)
  x <- gsub('\\)', '</font>\\)', x)
  return(x)
}

add_style <- function(x, style){
  x <- paste0('<div ', style, '>', x, '</div>')
  return(x)
}

add_in_progress <- function(x){
  x <- paste0(x, '<font size="1" color="red">', '(In Progress)', '</font>')
  return(x)
}

# define the style you want to apply where the condition hold
style <- 'style="background-color:darkred;font-weight:bold;color:white;"'

condition_1 <- Dataframe$Marking=='Hold' & Dataframe$percentage.1_num > 10
condition_2 <- Dataframe$batch_no==8 & Dataframe$percentage.2_num > 10


Html_Table<-
  Dataframe  %>%
  mutate(`Marking` = add_font(`Marking`),
         `batch_no` = add_font(`batch_no`)) %>% 
  # add the style where the condition holds
  mutate(percentage = ifelse(condition_1,
                             add_style(percentage, style),
                             percentage),
         # Marking = ifelse(condition_1,
         #                  add_style(Marking, style),
         #                  Marking),
         percentage.1 = ifelse(condition_2,
                               add_style(percentage.1, style),
                               percentage.1),
         # batch_no = ifelse(condition_2,
         #                   add_style(batch_no, style),
         #                   batch_no)
         ) %>%
  # add in progress where the condition holds
  mutate(Marking = ifelse(Marking=='S3', 
                          add_in_progress(Marking), 
                          Marking))  %>%
  mutate(batch_no = ifelse(batch_no=='9', 
                           add_in_progress(batch_no), 
                           batch_no)) %>% 
  # select the columns you want to show
  select(names_orig) %>%  
  # give it to tableHTML, you could also set the headers you want to show
  # and replace character NA with the empty string
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE, 
            escape = FALSE,
            widths = rep(100, 9),
            replace_NA = '',
            headers = names_orig %>% gsub('.[1-9]', '', .),
            caption = "Dataframe: Test", 
            border = 0) %>%
  # header style
  add_css_header(css = list(c('background-color', 'border-top', 'border-bottom'), 
                            c('lightgreen', '3px solid black', '3px solid black')), 
                 headers = 1:ncol(Dataframe)) %>% 
  # last row style
  add_css_row(css = list(c('background-color', 'font-weight'), 
                         c('yellow', 'bold')), 
              rows = nrow(Dataframe)+1)

Html_Table
```

[image]

Comment: The red color highlight should be for percentage of `Marking` and percentage of `batch_no`. Also, if there any way to convert font color of `(In Progress)` in red.

Comment: Thanks a lot to provide the required answer with the expected output.

Comment: Sure!  You can change the styling and conditions any way you like now, see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood correctly all your needs but here is an answer made with package `flextable`.

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
    ~seq, ~count1, ~percentage1,  ~Marking, ~count2, ~percentage2, ~batch_no, ~count3, ~percentage3,
    "FRD", 1, "12.50%", "S1", "2", "25.00%", "6", "1", "12.50%",
    "FHL", 1, "12.50%", "S2", "1", "12.50%", "7", "2", "25.00%",
    "ABC", 2, "25.00%", "S3", "1", "12.50%", "8", "2", "45.00%",
    "DEF", 1, "12.50%", "Hold", "2", "45.00%", "9", "1", "12.50%",
    "XYZ", 1, "12.50%", "NA", "1", "12.50%", "NA", "1", "12.50%",
    "ZZZ", 1, "12.50%", "(Blank)", "1", "12.50%", "(Blank)", "1", "12.50%",
    "FRD", 1, "12.50%", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    "NA",  1, "12.50%", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    "(Blank)", 0, "0.00%", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    "Total", 8, "112.50%", NA_character_, "8", "100.00%", NA_character_, "8", "100.00%"
  )
dat$percentage1 <- gsub("%", "", dat$percentage1) %>% as.double()
dat$percentage2 <- gsub("%", "", dat$percentage2) %>% as.double()
dat$percentage3 <- gsub("%", "", dat$percentage3) %>% as.double()


# I need to add table header color as light green 
# with bold font and last row of the table as orange 
# with bold font.
flextable(dat) %>% 
  fontsize(size = 11, part = "all") %>% 
  bold(part = "header") %>% 
  color(color = "#90EE90", part = "header") %>% 
  color(color = "orange", i = ~ seq %in% "Total") %>% 
  bold(i = ~ seq %in% "Total") %>% 
#' Also, Need to add the condition that if Percentage of Hold 
#' in marking and Percentage of 8 in batch_no is >25% mark it 
#' as a dark red with bold white font.
  color(i = ~ percentage1 > 10 & Marking %in% "Hold", 
        j = c("count1", "percentage1", "Marking"),
        color = "red", part = "body") %>% 
  color(i = ~ percentage2 > 10 & batch_no %in% "8", 
        j = c("count2", "percentage2", "batch_no"),
        color = "red", part = "body") %>% 
  bold(i = ~ percentage1 > 10 & Marking %in% "Hold", 
       j = c("count1", "percentage1", "Marking"),) %>% 
  bold(i = ~ percentage2 > 10 & batch_no %in% "8",
       j = c("count2", "percentage2", "batch_no")) %>% 

#' If possible, can we add the suffix in S3 as S3 (In Progress) 
#' and 9 as `9 (In Progress) where the font of (In Progress) will 
#' be 2 font less than variable name.
#' The added text (In Progress) should be in orange font with bold.
  compose(i = ~ Marking %in% "S3", j = "Marking", 
          value = as_paragraph(
            "S3 ", 
            as_chunk("(In Progress)", 
                     props = fp_text(color = "orange", bold = TRUE, font.size = 5.5))
            )
  ) %>% 
  autofit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted but getting error while installing `flextable` library in R.  Error Message `Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘flextable’ had non-zero exit status`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `kableExtra` rather than `htmlTable`...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

Dataframe<-
   tribble(
       ~seq, ~count1, ~percentage1,  ~Marking, ~count2, ~Percentage2, ~batch_no, ~count3, ~Percentage3,
      "FRD",       1,     "12.50%",      "S1",     "2",     "25.00%",       "6",     "1",     "12.50%",
      "FHL",       1,     "12.50%",      "S2",     "1",     "12.50%",       "7",     "2",     "25.00%",
      "ABC",       2,     "25.00%",      "S3",     "1",     "12.50%",       "8",     "2",     "45.00%",
      "DEF",       1,     "12.50%",    "Hold",     "2",     "45.00%",       "9",     "1",     "12.50%",
      "XYZ",       1,     "12.50%",      "NA",     "1",     "12.50%",      "NA",     "1",     "12.50%",
      "ZZZ",       1,     "12.50%", "(Blank)",     "1",     "12.50%", "(Blank)",     "1",     "12.50%",
      "FRD",       1,     "12.50%",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",
       "NA",       1,     "12.50%",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",
  "(Blank)",       0,      "0.00%",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",
    "Total",       8,    "112.50%",       "-",     "8",    "100.00%",       "-",     "8",    "100.00%"
          )

test1 <- expression(Marking == "Hold" & as.numeric(str_remove(Percentage2, "%")) > 25.00)
test2 <- expression(batch_no == "8" & as.numeric(str_remove(Percentage3, "%")) > 25.00)

Dataframe  %>%
  mutate(Percentage2 = cell_spec(Percentage2,
                                 "html",
                                 background = ifelse(eval(test1), "red", ""),
                                 color = ifelse(eval(test1), "white", "black")),
         Percentage3 = cell_spec(Percentage3,
                                 "html",
                                 background = ifelse(eval(test2), "red", ""),
                                 color = ifelse(eval(test2), "white", "black")))  %>%
         kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE)  %>%
         kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = FALSE)  %>%
         row_spec(0, bold = TRUE, background = "lightgreen") %>%
         row_spec(10, bold = TRUE, background = "yellow")  %>%
         save_kable(file = "temptable.html")

browseURL("temptable.html")
```

Comment: It worked one time, Now i'm getting error `Error in xml_children(x)[[search]] : subscript out of bounds`. Also, I need the html in html table format which i can send email using mailR library.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to style cells based on a condition in another column with `tableHtml`, so here's another attempt with package `gt`.

A few cautionary notes:

- `gt` does not include javascript bootstrap code, as `kableExtra`, but the html file still includes the CSS code.
- I don't understand your request with the prefix, so I ignored that.
- I considered the conditions *separately* rather than together.
- Consolidating all missing values to `NA` would allow `gt` to deal with the percent signs *etc.*, rather than including them as text (which makes things more complicated, especially for testing the conditions).

All in all, this code should be easily modifiable to suit your needs more closely :

```
library(tibble)
library(gt)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)


# data with the requested use cases :
Dataframe <-
  tribble(
    ~seq,      ~count1, ~percentage1, ~Marking,  ~count2, ~Percentage2, ~batch_no, ~count3, ~Percentage3,
    "FRD",     1,       "12.50%",     "S1",      "2",     "25.00%",     "6",       "1",     "12.50%",
    "FHL",     1,       "12.50%",     "S2",      "1",     "12.50%",     "7",       "2",     "25.00%",
    "ABC",     2,       "25.00%",     "S3",      "1",     "12.50%",     "8",       "2",     "45.00%",
    "ABC",     2,       "25.00%",     "S3",      "1",     "12.50%",     "9",       "2",     "17.00%",
    "DEF",     1,       "12.50%",     "Hold",    "2",     "45.00%",     "9",       "1",     "12.50%",
    "XYZ",     1,       "12.50%",     "NA",      "1",     "12.50%",     "NA",      "1",     "12.50%",
    "ZZZ",     1,       "12.50%",     "(Blank)", "1",     "12.50%",     "(Blank)", "1",     "12.50%",
    "FRD",     1,       "12.50%",     "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",
    "NA",      1,       "12.50%",     "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",
    "(Blank)", 0,       "0.00%",      "-",       "-",     "-",          "-",       "-",     "-",
    "Total",   8,       "112.50%",    "-",       "8",     "100.00%",    "-",       "8",     "100.00%"
  )


test1 <- expression(Marking == "Hold" & as.numeric(str_remove(Percentage2, "%")) > 25.00)
test2 <- expression(batch_no == "8" & as.numeric(str_remove(Percentage3, "%")) > 25.00)
test3 <- expression(Marking == "S3" & batch_no == "9")


newtab <-
  Dataframe  %>%
  mutate(Marking = ifelse(eval(test3), paste0(Marking, " (In progress)"), Marking))  %>%
  gt() %>%
  #
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = "lightgreen"),
                        cell_text(weight = "bold")),
            locations = cells_column_labels(columns = 1:9)) %>%
  #
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = "yellow"),
                        cell_text(weight = "bold")),
            locations = cells_body(columns = 1:9, rows = nrow(Dataframe)) %>%
  #
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = "red"),
                        cell_text(color = "white", weight = "bold")),
            locations = cells_body(columns = c("Marking", "Percentage2"),
                                  rows = eval(test1))) %>%
  #
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = "red"),
                        cell_text(color = "white", weight = "bold")),
            locations = cells_body(columns = c("batch_no", "Percentage3"),
                                  rows = eval(test2))) %>%
  #
  tab_style(style = list(cell_text(size = px(2))),
            locations = cells_body(columns = c("Marking"),
                                   rows = str_detect(string = Marking, pattern = "progress")))

gtsave(newtab, file = "gttable.html")
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to add `(In Progress)` with two font small where `Marking` value is S3 and batch_no is 9. It should look line `S3 (In Progress)` in htmltable.

Comment: Getting error `Error: All column or row indices given must be present in `data_tbl`.`.

Comment: Also getting error `rror in sass_options() : could not find function "strrep"`

Comment: See edits for the `S3 (In progress)`. As for the errors you get, make sure the packages are installed properly to their latest version, and with all dependencies... I don't know for the first error, but `strrep()` is a `base` function, so you should have that.

Comment: getting file like ".html", I need `tableHTML`.